# Default Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-2013

My sharepoint site has only one site collection.

When accessed the default URL http://example.com it takes to http://example.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/default.aspx

Instead i want it to go to http://example.com/sites/siteCollection1/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx

I have been googling for a long time and found no simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a host header.  This is from 2010, but concepts are the same:

http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=929

Comment: Thanks Stan. This is for using a dns name instead of the server name. I got that handled by using alternate access mapping. The problem is when i access example.com it should go to http://example.com/sites/siteCollection1/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx. But it goes to http://example.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/default.aspx which is the user profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Site Settings > Look and Feel > Welcome page and then entering the page you want in there?

Comment: Thanks cptasker. Tried this one. It's related only the site im looking. I'm looking for a top level setting to redirect to the team site instead of profile page